# get elements with pair index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this example

| index | positions | list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | ('a','b','c','d','e','f') |
| 1 | 3 | ('g','h','i','j','k','l') |

Result table should be

| index | result |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ('a','c') |
| 1 | ('g','i','k') |

I'm struggling with this and not getting a good result. DataFrame has several rows, 2 is just in the example.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the relation between "positions" and "list" columns?

Comment: In the firs row I need just the first 2 pair index positions of the list in column list. In the second row I need the first 3 pair index positions of the list in column list.

Comment: What is the result of `print(type(df['list'].iloc[0]))`?

Comment: Why are B and h not included?

Comment: b and h are not included because I want the index pair: 0,2,4,6,8. But as many as positions say. So in row 1 I need indexs 0,2. In row 2 I need indexs 0,2,4

Comment: @richardec type is list

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['list'][:row['positions']], axis=1)
```

Comment: Sorry but this code returns a,b  and g,h,i not the paired indexes.

Comment: @QuimQuadrada Try `df.apply(lambda row: row['list'][:2 * row['positions']:2], axis=1)` instead.

Comment: Great! It works